# Blenderの「User Preferences」での変更が反映されない事例

Tags: blender

Edit Modeの時の頂点の追加をCtrl＋右クリックで行いたいと思い、
User Preferencesで「Add Vertex」の項目を上書きし、
Save User Settingで保存しました。

しかし、何度試みても、Ctrl＋左クリックでの追加になってしまいます。

すでにCtrl＋右クリックに他のショートカットが振り当てられているのかと思い、
すべて検索して削除しましたが何も変わりませんでした。

どこか変更場所などの間違いがございましたら、お教えいただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Add Vertex は別カテゴリ(Curve)になっています。Mesh 内を探さしましょう。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]